# How to catch enwrapped exception in Junit test case?

Tags: java, junit

I have a test case as

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void test() throws Exception{
  ..test content...
}
```

Because I'm using Java Reflection in my test case so the IllegalArgumentException is enwrapped in InvocationTargetException, how can I catch expected IllegalArgumentException instead of InvocationTargetException.

Error message shows as

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException>
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

Comment: Problably the answer is already out there, but personally I would simply implement a custom hamcrest matcher that checks for the cause being an IllegalArgumentException - and then use the ExpectedException rule to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a JUnit way of doing it - you probably have to do it manually in the test, e.g.:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    try {
       runTest();
       fail();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
       if( ! (x.getCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException)) {
           fail();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The assertion could be made clearer with `assertTrue( expected.getCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException );`

Comment: Ugly a hell. Using an ExpectedException rule (let's call it "expectedException") you could simply write... `expectedException.expect( hasCause( IllegalArgumentException.class ));` by simply implementing a HasCause hamcrest Matcher.

Comment: Well, if you want to go pulling in other libraries then https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/ is a lot neater still.

Comment: Nice suggestion, like it.